# Adding Search for layer in ArcGIS Maps SDK for .NET MAUI samples

Tags: .net, maui

I am using this tutorial https://developers.arcgis.com/net/maui/sample-code/find-place// to try and add a search for my FeatureLayer hosted on ArcGIS Online. The map appears but there is no search box if I remove all the errors.

Also please explain if all I need is to change the _geolocator URI to get the search for the layer.

These are two questions, please bear with me

The errors appear with the following code because there is no reference in the code

```
// Enable all controls now that the locator task is ready.
            MySearchBox.IsEnabled = true;
            MyLocationBox.IsEnabled = true;
            MySearchButton.IsEnabled = true;
            MySearchRestrictedButton.IsEnabled = true;
```

Please, which reference am I missing?

My MainPage.xaml looks as below:

```
<esri:MapView x:Name="MainMapView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Map="{Binding Map, Source={StaticResource MapViewModel}}" />

<toolkit:SearchView  x:Name="MainSearchView" GeoView="{Binding Source={Reference MainMapView}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"   />
```

Comment: you keep saying "errors" without specifying what the specific errors are

Answer (score 0):

The errors were raised because of my MainPage.xaml not having the necessary xaml MySearchBox (Entry) and other controls.

Just added the controls and everything works fine.